# internet access on ICS and Jelly Bean

Tags: android, permissions, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've been wondering on how to build an aplication on ICS and Jelly Bean.
whenever it tries to connect to the database, it always force closes.
I've tested on ginggerbead and no problems show up.

I'm using this permission on the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Is the database remote? What exception do you get? The code you use to connect to the database?

Comment: It's probably because you're accessing the internet on Main thread. Put your internet access code into an AsyncTask and it'll be fine

Comment: @VinaySShenoy But this is giving RE even on froyo if I am not wrong

Comment: @BorisStrandjev : i've got this error on the logcat
<br/>
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rdk.resto/com.rdk.resto.sort_list}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
<br/>
@VinaySShenoy : thanx, i'll try that. anyway, what is RE?

Comment: i'am using this code to acces the database, i'm parsing the data using json 

<br/> <final String url = this.getString(R.string.urlServer); //api's url Map<String, String> lempar = new HashMap<String, String>(); lempar.put("aksi", "sort_food"); lempar.put("gol", get_index); HttpRequestApi http = new HttpRequestApi(url, lempar, HttpRequestApi.Method.POST); String response = http.sendRequest();

*so sory, i don't how to use tag for code in this forum

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#asynctask

Comment: @VinaySShenoy : thanx dude, i've just found the same question asked. i'll try it later after my final exam.
<br/>
do this permission have any effect on the project?

` <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: Nope. Although, most applications which use Internet permission also use this. This permission can be used to check if you are connected to the network or not.